# Pull single Instagram Feed from single user with hashtag using API

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am going to be building a website for an upcoming client who would like to pull an Instagram feed of all posts WITHIN THEIR ACCOUNT with a specific hashtag (use #helloworld from @myaccount as an example).

Recent updates to the Instagram API make this process slightly confusing. We can authenticate through the GUI interface once through the client's account and then store the access token. That being said, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to check if the auth token has expired and, if it has, request a new one without requiring us to go through the GUI "Allow this app to use..." interface. We are worried the feed functionality may break on our site as a result of this if the token were to expire for some reason. Are we missing something here? Is there a way to continue to re-authenticate through Instagram without having to do this? We could not find any clear information through the documentation.

Second, we will be running this on a PHP-driven site. How exactly would we go about pulling all posts from a SINGLE ACCOUNT with a PARTICULAR hashtag once the auth code has been received and verified as valid. We MUST limit the hashtags to only the single account. Any help would be great, as there doesn't seem to be great documentation since Instagram updated their API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to authenticate automatically without oauth redirects.

If the `access_token` is invalid then API calls will have a error response

```
{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}
```

(Your app does not seem to fall into one of the Instagram approved usecases, so I'm not sure your app will be approved by Instagram, might want to check that first)